# Kafka interactive queries returns store that doesn't contain key

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams application that utilizes [Interactive Queries](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html).
The application stores key-value pairs in a state store and exposes a REST endpoint that allows querying the local and remote stores by key. The host and port of the instances are configured via `application.server` in each instance as stated in the documentation.

When running the app in a test environment where instances get restarted, `streams.metadataForKey` returns a host+port combination (as expected since I sent messages with this key).

When I query the state store on the returned host+port instance via REST API, `streams.metadataForKey` returns the local instance's `application.server` values (as expected) however **`keyValueStore.get(key)` returns `null`**.

**It seems as though the state store metadata is incorrect.**

Topology:

```
 internal fun getTopology(): Topology? {
    val builder = StreamsBuilder()
    builder.addStateStore(
        Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(EMPLOYEE_STATE_STORE_NAME),
            Serdes.StringSerde(),
            personSerde()
        )
    )
    val inputStream = builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), personSerde()))
    inputStream
        // Print for debug
        .peek { empId, personDetails -> println("[Consumed record] key (empID) = $empId, value (personDetails) = $personDetails") }
        .groupByKey().reduce(
            { aggPersonDetails, newDetails ->
                aggPersonDetails.copy(favoriteBooks = aggPersonDetails.favoriteBooks + newDetails.favoriteBooks)
            },
            Materialized.`as`(AGGREGATED_EMPLOYEE_STATE_STORE_NAME)
        )
        .toStream()
        .transform({ EmployeeStoreUpdater() }, EMPLOYEE_STATE_STORE_NAME)
        .peek { key, value -> println("emp $key favorite books: ${value.favoriteBooks}") }
        .to(
            OUTPUT_TOPIC_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS,
            Produced.with(
                Serdes.StringSerde(),
                personSerde()
            )
        )

    return builder.build()
}
```

`application.server` and other configs:

```
val defaultConfigs = mapOf(
StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG to "employee-details-app",
StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG to brokerUrl,
// useful for testing, but in practice the default is latest
ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG to "latest",
).toProperties()

init {
configs[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG] = rpcEndpoint
logger.info("rpcEndpoint = $rpcEndpoint")
streams = KafkaStreams(getTopology(), getConfigs())
localServerConfig = configs[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG].toString()
logger.info("rpcEndpoint=$rpcEndpoint")
}
```

store lookup by key logic:

```
 override suspend fun getEmployeeNumFavoriteBooks(
    storeName: String,
    employeeId: String,
    remoteCallsEndpoint: String,
    logIdProperties: LogIdProperties
): NumEmployeeFavBooksResponse {
    // Find the store that has key employeeId
    val queryMetadata = streams.queryMetadataForKey(storeName, employeeId, Serdes.String().serializer())
    val activeHost = queryMetadata.activeHost()
    val storeDetails = "${activeHost.host()}:${activeHost.port()}"
    if (localServerConfig == storeDetails) {
        logger.info("EmployeeId $employeeId is on this instance's state-store, querying local store $storeDetails")
        // Key is in local store
        val storeQueryParams = StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(
            storeName,
            QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore<String, PersonDetails>()
        )
        val keyValueStore = streams.store(storeQueryParams)
        var personDetails = keyValueStore.get(employeeId)
        if (personDetails == null) {
            logger.debug("employee $employeeId is not in local state store $activeHost, going to query standby instances...")
            personDetails = searchStandbyStateStores(queryMetadata, remoteCallsEndpoint, employeeId, logIdProperties)
        }
        return NumEmployeeFavBooksResponse(employeeId, personDetails.favoriteBooks.size.toLong())
    }
    logger.info("EmployeeId $employeeId is on a different instance's state-store, going to query $storeDetails")
    @Suppress("HttpUrlsUsage") val response: NumEmployeeFavBooksResponse =
        httpClient.get("http://$storeDetails/$remoteCallsEndpoint/${logIdProperties.transactionId}")
    return NumEmployeeFavBooksResponse(employeeId, response.numFavoriteBooks)
}

   private suspend fun searchStandbyStateStores(
    queryMetadata: KeyQueryMetadata,
    remoteCallsEndpoint: String,
    employeeId: String,
    logIdProperties: LogIdProperties
): PersonDetails? {
    val inSyncStandbys = queryMetadata.standbyHosts()
    logger.debug("standby hosts: $inSyncStandbys")

    for (standbyHost in inSyncStandbys) {
        val standbyRpcHost = "${standbyHost.host()}:${standbyHost.port()}"
        try {
            return httpClient.get("http://$standbyRpcHost/$remoteCallsEndpoint/${logIdProperties.transactionId}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.error(("Querying standby instance $standbyRpcHost for employeeId $employeeId failed"))
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

The HTTP GET call calls the same code (function `getEmployeeNumFavoriteBooks`) on the host it is sent to.

**The logs show:**

timestamp: 14:19:15.959

host: host1
message: EmployeeId 2147483645 **is on this instance's state-store, querying local store host1:12573**

timestamp: 14:19:15.959

host: host1

message: employee 2147483645 **is not in local state store HostInfo{host='host1', port=12573}**, going to query standby instances...

**There are no standby instances:**

timestamp: 14:19:15.959

host: host1

message: standby hosts: []

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be a matter of the serializing classes being different on the Server and Client (Kafka producer) sides.

When I first added messages to the input topic I used [KCAT](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat). I didn't find an option to provide my own serialization classes with this tool.

When testing with a different Kafka producer client ([confluentinc/cp-kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/) docker image) and explicitly specifying the serialization classes in the creation of the producer the ( `--property key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer \     --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer`) I got "new" keys in my state store (meaning they were recognized as different values).